# Why when I call save on an object that I instantiate within the same class does it not return true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I've created a class method and within that class method I instantiate another object of the same class. While trying to save this object I'm getting false according to my test, but I can't figure out why.

As far as the implementation of deposit. I've tested transaction.credit by itself and it works as intended. The problem is the transaction.save is not returning TRUE. Anding (&&) these two methods together should return true only if both methods evaluate to TRUE.

```
class Transaction
  .
  .
  .
  def self.deposit(account, amount, description, task_description_id)
    # create credit transaction
    transaction = Transaction.new
    transaction.description = description
    transaction.task_description_id = task_description_id

    transaction.credit(account, amount) && transaction.save
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

My test

```
describe "when performing account deposit" do
  before { @flag = Transaction.deposit(@discrete_task.commitment_account, 10000, "transfer", 4) }
  it { @discrete_task.commitment_account.balance.to_f.should == 10000 }
  it { @flag.should be_true }
end
```

Comment: Try ``transaction.save!`` it will display you possible save errors

Comment: It's always the simple stuff...your suggestion help point me in the right direction thanks @23tux!!!

Answer (score 0):

My test failed due to not fulfilling validation requirements, therefore my object would not save...Thanks to @23tux for helping me to get the error messages I needed to get this figured out.